# Mongo nested array update with conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to update userAns,ansBody fields of the below-mentioned collection. Where conditions will have userId ,userQuestions._id and quesId.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b9624b56b0fe824352e887a"), 
"userId" : ObjectId("5b8fd089ee2e6c07765ba024"), 
"userQuestions" : [
    {
        "testStatus" : NumberInt(1), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9624b56b0fe824352e887f"), 
        "questionsId" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b9624b56b0fe824352e8885"), 
                "quesId" : ObjectId("5b94f1e97b8adc3d46854518"), 
                "userAns" : "", 
                "ansBody" : "", 
                "ansStatus" : ""
            }
```

What I have tried

```
  let paramObj={
  userId:"5b8fd089ee2e6c07765ba024",
  quesSetId:"5b9624b56b0fe824352e887b",
  quesId:"5b9619311d9b1b1834f2cd23",
  ansId:"5b9619311d9b1b1834f2cd27",
  ansBody:"abc123"
}
let questionSet=await QuestionSet.update({userId:paramObj.userId,"userQuestions._id":paramObj.quesSetId},
  { $set: {"userQuestions.$[t].questionsId.$[u].ansBody": paramObj.ansBody} },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "t.quesId":paramObj.quesId },{"u.quesId": paramObj.quesId} ] } );
```

event though It gives me output as modified, the document is not getting updated.

Comment: Try   `let paramObj={   userId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b8fd089ee2e6c07765ba024");   quesSetId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b9624b56b0fe824352e887b"),   quesId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b9619311d9b1b1834f2cd23"),   ansId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b9619311d9b1b1834f2cd27"),   ansBody:"abc123" } let questionSet=await QuestionSet.update({userId:paramObj.userId},   { $set: {"userQuestions.$[t].questionsId.$[u].ansBody": paramObj.ansBody} },   { arrayFilters: [ { "t._id": param.quesSetId"}{"u.quesId": paramObj.quesId} ] } );`

Comment: This also should work. `let questionSet=await QuestionSet.update({userId:paramObj.userId,"userQuestions._id":paramObj.quesSetId},   { $set: {"userQuestions.$.questionsId.$[u].ansBody": paramObj.ansBody} },   { arrayFilters: [ {"u.quesId": paramObj.quesId} ] } );`

Comment: it had some syntax errors I have changed that still it is  not working

Comment: Please make sure the ids are matching and you are 3.6 server version.

Comment: Mongo is v3.6.3 and I have double checked the ids. it is not working.. :(

Comment: Can you try setting the flag in shell and try ?  `use admin db.adminCommand ({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6"})`

Comment: "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.6\", $db: \"admin\" }",

I am using studio 3t and db is in remote server . Will it affect login If i create a user?

Comment: okay.  You don't need a new user. Do you have an admin user ? Can you try the query in studio 3t and see if it works ?  Replace  QuestionSet with name of collection and mongoose object id with `ObjectId`.

Comment: I have tried the query in studio 3t shell and it gave ok status. Then I have called the request.Still it is not updating.also QuestionSet is the model name

Comment: And i ran the query like this in studio 3t shell like this db.getCollection("cg_questionsets").update({userId:"5b8fd089ee2e6c07765ba024","userQuestions._id":"5b9624b56b0fe824352e887b"},
      { $set: {"userQuestions.$.questionsId.$[u].ansBody": "test answer"} }, 
      { arrayFilters: [ {"u.quesId": "5b9619421d9b1b1834f2cd28"} ] } )
and it is gaving WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
status

Comment: wrap id inside ObjectId() and try

Comment: As you mentioned in first comment  it worked when the param object changed like this let paramObj={ userId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b8fd089ee2e6c07765ba024").
Thank you very very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the object id as  ObjectId type.

For that, if you are using mongoose,   convert the string into mongoose object type using.

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId('id');
```

I think it will solve your problem.

[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js/)